# Deprecation notice - first test only; not related to code?

Tags: php, symfony

The first run of functional tests in a 2.8.9 application returns deprecation notices; subsequent tests without making any changes to code do not return deprecation notices.  Before the first tests are run, test environment cache is cleared.  How best to deal with the notices?

Edit:

Review of test log strongly suggests the notices are unrelated to application code.  Lines 1 - 10 of test log:

```
[2016-08-02 09:27:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2016-08-02 09:27:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2016-08-02 09:27:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2016-08-02 09:27:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2016-08-02 09:27:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2016-08-02 09:27:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2016-08-02 09:27:30] php.INFO: The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom class is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the random_bytes() function instead. {"type":16384,"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Util\\SecureRandom.php","line":14,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Util\\SecureRandom.php","line":14,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\composer\\ClassLoader.php","line":412,"args":["G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Util\\SecureRandom.php"],"function":"include"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\composer\\ClassLoader.php","line":301,"function":"Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile"},{"function":"loadClass","class":"Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader","type":"->"},{"function":"spl_autoload_call"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\jms\\aop-bundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass.php","line":116,"function":"class_exists"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\jms\\aop-bundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass.php","line":65,"function":"processDefinition","class":"JMS\\AopBundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\Compiler.php","line":104,"function":"process","class":"JMS\\AopBundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder.php","line":597,"function":"compile","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\Compiler","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache","line":2725,"function":"compile","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\AppKernel.php","line":67,"function":"initializeContainer","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache","line":2503,"function":"initializeContainer","class":"AppKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand.php","line":134,"function":"boot","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand.php","line":96,"function":"warmup","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command.php","line":259,"function":"execute","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":863,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":192,"function":"doRunCommand","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Console\\Application.php","line":92,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":123,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\console","line":21,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"}]} []
[2016-08-02 09:27:30] php.INFO: The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom class is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the random_bytes() function instead. {"type":16384,"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Util\\SecureRandom.php","line":14,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Util\\SecureRandom.php","line":14,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\composer\\ClassLoader.php","line":412,"args":["G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Util\\SecureRandom.php"],"function":"include"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\composer\\ClassLoader.php","line":301,"function":"Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile"},{"function":"loadClass","class":"Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader","type":"->"},{"function":"spl_autoload_call"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\jms\\aop-bundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass.php","line":116,"function":"class_exists"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\jms\\aop-bundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass.php","line":65,"function":"processDefinition","class":"JMS\\AopBundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\Compiler.php","line":104,"function":"process","class":"JMS\\AopBundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder.php","line":597,"function":"compile","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\Compiler","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache","line":2725,"function":"compile","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\AppKernel.php","line":67,"function":"initializeContainer","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache","line":2503,"function":"initializeContainer","class":"AppKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand.php","line":134,"function":"boot","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand.php","line":96,"function":"warmup","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command.php","line":259,"function":"execute","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":863,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":192,"function":"doRunCommand","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Console\\Application.php","line":92,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":123,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\console","line":21,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"}]} []
[2016-08-02 09:27:30] php.INFO: The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext class is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage or Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker instead. {"type":16384,"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\SecurityContext.php","line":14,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\SecurityContext.php","line":14,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\composer\\ClassLoader.php","line":412,"args":["G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\SecurityContext.php"],"function":"include"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\composer\\ClassLoader.php","line":301,"function":"Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile"},{"function":"loadClass","class":"Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader","type":"->"},{"function":"spl_autoload_call"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\jms\\aop-bundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass.php","line":116,"function":"class_exists"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\jms\\aop-bundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass.php","line":65,"function":"processDefinition","class":"JMS\\AopBundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\Compiler.php","line":104,"function":"process","class":"JMS\\AopBundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder.php","line":597,"function":"compile","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\Compiler","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache","line":2725,"function":"compile","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\AppKernel.php","line":67,"function":"initializeContainer","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache","line":2503,"function":"initializeContainer","class":"AppKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand.php","line":134,"function":"boot","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand.php","line":96,"function":"warmup","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command.php","line":259,"function":"execute","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":863,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":192,"function":"doRunCommand","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Console\\Application.php","line":92,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":123,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\console","line":21,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"}]} []
[2016-08-02 09:27:30] php.INFO: The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext class is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage or Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker instead. {"type":16384,"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\SecurityContext.php","line":14,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\SecurityContext.php","line":14,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\composer\\ClassLoader.php","line":412,"args":["G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\SecurityContext.php"],"function":"include"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\composer\\ClassLoader.php","line":301,"function":"Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile"},{"function":"loadClass","class":"Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader","type":"->"},{"function":"spl_autoload_call"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\jms\\aop-bundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass.php","line":116,"function":"class_exists"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\jms\\aop-bundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass.php","line":65,"function":"processDefinition","class":"JMS\\AopBundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\Compiler.php","line":104,"function":"process","class":"JMS\\AopBundle\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\PointcutMatchingPass","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder.php","line":597,"function":"compile","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\Compiler","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache","line":2725,"function":"compile","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\AppKernel.php","line":67,"function":"initializeContainer","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache","line":2503,"function":"initializeContainer","class":"AppKernel","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand.php","line":134,"function":"boot","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand.php","line":96,"function":"warmup","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command.php","line":259,"function":"execute","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\CacheClearCommand","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":863,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":192,"function":"doRunCommand","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Console\\Application.php","line":92,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":123,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"G:\\Documents\\workspace\\projectmana\\app\\console","line":21,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"}]} []
```

The sequence of commands and results as copied directly from a terminal window are:

```
G:\Documents\workspace\projectmana>php app/console cache:clear -e=test

 // Clearing the cache for the test environment with debug true


 [OK] Cache for the "test" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.



G:\Documents\workspace\projectmana>phpunit -c app
PHPUnit 5.4.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.....................................                             37 / 37 (100%)

Time: 1.04 minutes, Memory: 78.00MB

OK (37 tests, 62 assertions)

Remaining deprecation notices (2)

The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom class is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the random_bytes() function instead: 1x
    1x in AdminTest::setup from Truckee\ProjectmanaBundle\Tests

The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext class is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage or Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker instead: 1x
    1x in AdminTest::setup from Truckee\ProjectmanaBundle\Tests


G:\Documents\workspace\projectmana>phpunit -c app
PHPUnit 5.4.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.....................................                             37 / 37 (100%)

Time: 52.29 seconds, Memory: 70.00MB

OK (37 tests, 62 assertions)

G:\Documents\workspace\projectmana>
```

The test & fixture that triggers the notices:

```
class AdminTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function setup()
    {
        $this->client = static::makeClient();
        $this->client->followRedirects();
        $this->fixtures = $this->loadFixtures([
                    'Truckee\ProjectmanaBundle\DataFixtures\Test\AdminUser',
                ]);
    }
...
}

class AdminUser extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        $admin = $userManager->createUser();
        $admin->setUsername('admin');
        $admin->setFname('Benny');
        $admin->setSname('Borko');
        $admin->setEmail('admin@bogus.info');
        $admin->setPlainPassword('manapw');
        $admin->setEnabled(true);
        $admin->addRole('ROLE_ADMIN');

        $userManager->updateUser($admin, true);
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1; // the order in which fixtures will be loaded
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I hear otherwise, I will assume that the deprecation notices have nothing to do with my code.  I've created a separate application using my code on a symfony 3.1 platform.  Functional tests pass without any notices or errors.  The deprecation notices must then be an artifact of Symfony 2.8 code.